# module exports does not export the variable

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to creat a rest API, using the file routes.js (code bellow) but the module exports does not wotk, it does not export the const routes, if i put route it try to export, but routes makes it just dont wotk, i dont know why, this is the entire code until now

```
const routes = express.Router();

routes.get('/', (req, res) => {
    return res.json({ message: 'test' });
});

module.exports = routes;
```

i tried using insominia to debug this, it work on the index file, normaly, but when i use the routes file, it just does not work (code of index bellow)

```
const express = require('express')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const routes = require('./routes')

const app = express()

mongoose.connect(**url mongoose censored**)

app.use(express.json)
app.use(routes)

app.listen(3333)
```

someone can help me, please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`express.json` is a function that returns a middleware function when you call it (allowing you to pass arguments that will be used in the middleware function).   So, you need to use it like this:

```
app.use(express.json());
```

Also check if the `require` path is correct, you might need to provide first argument to `app.use` when using `router`

```
app.use('/',router)
```